# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC What is about PDO::FETCH_ARRAY?

Tags: php, pdo

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

The above example will fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set and output something similar to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => pear
            [0] => pear
            [COLOUR] => green
            [1] => green
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => watermelon
            [0] => watermelon
            [COLOUR] => pink
            [1] => pink
        )

)
```

Is there any option to get a result like the one `my_sql_fetch_array` returns, which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [0] => pear
            [1] => green
        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [0] => watermelon             
            [1] => pink
        )

)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php I did not see said about the option FETCH_NUM. Anywhere is works with your tip.
Thanks

Comment: Just for reference, FETCH_NUM is listed in the docs for fetch() not fetchAll(): http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

try use this

```
$data = $sth->fetch();
print_r($data);
```

Hope it will help you.