# Getting array in different format from data fetched using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

After executing a prepared SQL statement in PHP, I've doing a `fetchAll()`. This results in the following array:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 2
        [0] => 2
        [latitude] => 38.44560000
        [1] => 38.44560000
        [longitude] => -99.99999999
        [2] => -99.99999999
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 4
        [0] => 4
        [latitude] => 38.44560000
        [1] => 38.44560000
        [longitude] => -99.99999999
        [2] => -99.99999999
    )
)
```

I would like my array to look like this:

```
Array
(

    [0] => array('2','otheritem1details....','38.44560000','-99.99999999'),
    [1] => array('4','otheritem1details....','38.44560000','-99.99999999')
)
```

Do I have to take the data from the source array and manually compile it into a new array in the correct format? Or is there a way to fetch the data initially in the correct format?

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO::FETCH\_ASSOC What is about PDO::FETCH\_ARRAY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067721/pdofetch-assoc-what-is-about-pdofetch-array)

Comment: It's not quite the same - my desired output is different, see below for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) takes a [fetch style](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters) as an optional first parameter. This defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`.

From the manual:

> *PDO::FETCH_BOTH* (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

What you want is `PDO::FETCH_NUM`:

> *PDO::FETCH_NUM*: returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0

So your call to fetchAll would look something like `$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)`

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't quite do it though. It comes out like this:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 38.44560000
            [2] => -99.99999999
        )

It's a bit neater, but not the same.

Comment: Think I was just a little confused by the output of print_r to debug in my browser. One way or another, it's now fixed. So thanks, your answer really helped.